# Prove: $\frac{\sin A\sin2A + \sin3A\sin6A}{\sin A\cos2A + \sin3A\cos6A} = \tan5A$

Tags: trigonometry

I have already tried multiplying the whole fraction by $2$, which then through further simplification led me to:

$$\frac{\sin A\sin2A + \sin3A\sin6A}{\sin A\cos2A + \sin3A\cos6A},$$

i.e. I ended up where I started.

Comment: use product to sum formula

Comment: Three answers have appeared and yet so far I am the only one who's up-voted the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given fraction, after multiplication by $2$ in the numerator and denominator

$$S=\frac{\cos A-\cos 3A+\cos 3A-\cos 9A}{\sin 3A-\sin A+\sin 9A-\sin 3A}\\=\frac{2\sin 5A\sin 4A}{2\sin 4A \cos 5A  }=\tan 5A$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\sin a \sin b =-\frac{1}{2}(\cos(a+b)-\cos(a-b))
$$
$$
\cos a \cos b =\frac{1}{2}(\cos(a+b)+\cos(a-b))
$$

Answer (score 0):

Majorly you have to use these identities

$$\cos(α + β) = \cos(α)\cos(β) - \sin(α)\sin(β)$$

$$\cos(α - β) = \cos(α)\cos(β) + \sin(α)\sin(β)$$

And further is explained by @Samrat